# Laplace transformation with Dirac Delta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$$f(t)=2\int_0^t f(u)\cos (2(t-u))~du+3\sin(2t),t\geq 0$$

I find it hard to transform the first term, $f(u)\cos(2(t-u))$.

I think I should use this formula,

$$\cos at = \frac{s}{s^2 + a^2}$$

to get this solution as below,

$$F(s)=2F(s)\frac{s}{s^2+4}+3\frac{2}{s^2+4}$$

But I still don't understand how they transformed $f(u)\cos(2(t-u))$ to $F(s)\cdot \dfrac{s}{s^2 + 4}$

How did they manage to transform it? What happens to "$t-u$"?

I am aware of the Dirac Delta function, but this is not $U(t-u)$, its $cos(t-u)$, and it confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Remember that if $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are piecewise continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$, then the [convolution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html) integral of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, which we denote by $(f\ast g)(t)$ is:
$$(f\ast g)(t)=\int_0^t f(t-\tau)g(\tau) d\tau \tag{1}$$
Also, recall the following properties:
$$(f\ast g)(t)=(g\ast f)(t) \tag{2}$$
You can prove $(2)$ straight from the definition: Use the change of variable $u=t-\tau$.
$$\mathscr{L}\{(f\ast g)(t)\}=F(s)G(s) \tag{3}$$
Where $\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}=F(s)$ and $\mathscr{L}\{g(t)\}=G(s)$.